# Calender on webpage to MySQL database

Tags: mysql, database, calendar

I would like to make a calender schedule for my work. That means that everyday I work I will put it in a form, where it is connected to my MySQL databases. From a page I would like to see how many hours I had in a period. I was thinking that there was 2 of these icons:

http://www.calendar123.org/calendar123/november-2012-calendar-printable-16.jpg

where I could those a period, and get it displayed. I have the connection to my database etc, but how do I incorporate a calendar function like the picture on my webpage, where I can choose dates from my database? I am not familar with PHP, but I am working with html, xml, java, javascript, css and MySQL

Hope somebody can help me.

Best Regards
Mads

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to use the [jQuery datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) but there are tons of them out there.

UPDATE:

It acts like a textbox on the PHP side. You'll get a string date in your [$_REQUEST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php) array. You'll want to use the [strtotime()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function to convert that into a PHP timestamp. Then use the [date](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to convert that back into a MySQL formatted date like so:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $_REQUEST['date_html_id'])));
```

Now $date can be inserted directly into a MySQL DATE or DATETIME field.

Comment: That looks full cool, thanks for this. So can you give me a tip on how I get the specified date i choose to connect to the specified date in MySQL?